Kubuntu login screen keyboard layout dark magic
have installed Kubuntu 24 and during install I have set up DE keyboard, because this is what I had available at that time. Now I have bought a US keyboard, and after logging in, I have changed the layout to US. Super. This however has no effect on the login screen. What I have tried so far:
1 - The system settings app -> Startup and shutdown -> Login screen. This thing however does not provide options to change keyboard
2 - I have also tried service dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration and keyboard-setup restart. This was also fruitless. This is the top rated answer for this question.
3 - Then my last effort was adding
[Layout]
KeyboardLayout=us
to /etc/sddm.conf with no joy either.
I'm speechless and clueless, please help me out.
